# Add big bracket below/over tikz node

Tags: tikz-trees

How can I prolong the big bracket to not only cover `yyyy` but also the `uuuu` node?

```
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped]
\node[draw] {ppp\textsuperscript{p}}        
            child {
                node[draw, circle, label=right:
                    {$xxxx$}]
{}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {xx}
                node[below]  {$xxxx$}
            }
            child {
                node[draw, circle, label=right:
                    {$uuuu$}] 
{}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {uu}
                node[below]  {$uuuu$}
             }
            child {
                node[draw, circle,label=right:
                    {$yyyy \Bigg\} $}] 
{}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {yy}
                node[below]  {$yyyy$}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I `\smash`ed and `\raisebox`ed a zero-width `\rule` that had an enclosing right brace that followed it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped]
\node[draw] {ppp\textsuperscript{p}}        
            child {
                node[draw, circle, label=right:
                    {$xxxx$}]
{}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {xx}
                node[below]  {$xxxx$}
            }
            child {
                node[draw, circle, label=right:
                    {$uuuu$}] 
{}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {uu}
                node[below]  {$uuuu$}
             }
            child {
                node[draw, circle,label=right:
                    {$yyyy 
            \smash{\raisebox{-52pt}{$\left.\rule{0pt}{60pt}\right\}$}} $}] 
{}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {yy}
                node[below]  {$yyyy$}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add labels to the relevant nodes

```
            child {
                node[draw, circle, label=right:
                    {$uuuu$}] (U)
{}
```

and similarly for `(Y)` and then you can draw a brace as a decoration:

```
\draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=8pt},decorate] ($(Y)+(3.5em,1ex)$) -- ($(U)+(3.5em,-1ex)$);
```

The offsets here are needed because of the labels and to get the extra height.  I have specified these in terms of `ex` and `em` as these are units that depend on the font size.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped]
\node[draw] {ppp\textsuperscript{p}}        
            child {
                node[draw, circle, label=right:
                    {$xxxx$}]
{}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {xx}
                node[below]  {$xxxx$}
            }
            child {
                node[draw, circle, label=right:
                    {$uuuu$}] (U)
{}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {uu}
                node[below]  {$uuuu$}
             }
            child {
                node[draw, circle,label=right:
                    {$yyyy$}] (Y)
{}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {yy}
                node[below]  {$yyyy$}
    };
\draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=8pt},decorate] ($(Y)+(3.5em,1ex)$) -- ($(U)+(3.5em,-1ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew and @steven everything resolved!! your suggestions work perfect!!!